# Curious badge not working

Tags: discussion, support, bug

Hm strange behaviour of one badge.

So... I asked 3 questions, all three have positive score.

[What are the pros and cons of collecting parts yourself, versus getting a DIY kit and then modifying it?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/409/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-collecting-parts-yourself-versus-getting-a-diy-ki)

[How to choose a right 3D printer filament type?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/410/difference-between-pla-and-abs)

[Methods for smoothing 3D objects](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/413/how-to-smooth-3d-printed-objects-without-using-sanding)

My curious badge stays on 0/5. Why is that so?

Comment: meanwhile, I asked fourth question. It has 1 vote up, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked 3 questions on February 3rd, so that does not count for "on separate days".

Then, there is [a formula](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262817/480982) which is

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5
```

You have

```
(3 - 0 - 2 - ?) / 5 = 0.2
```

so this criterion is not met.